# Why do geom_smooth nls and the standalone nls give different fit results?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-fitting, nls

When I fit my data using geom_smooth nls, I get a really nice fit. But if I use the stand alone nls function to fit my data using the same equation and starting values, I get a much poorer fit.  I want to extract fit parameters so really need the standalone nls to generate the same fit as the geom_smooth nls.

Any suggestion/hint at what might be going on?

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c(4.63794469, 1.54525711, 0.51508570, 0.17169523, 0.05737664, 5.11623138, 1.70461130, 0.56820377, 0.18940126, 0.06329358, 0.02109786), 
                 "y" = c(0.1460101, 0.7081954, 0.9619413, 1.0192286, 1.0188301, 0.3114495, 0.7602488, 0.8205661, 0.9741323, 1.0922553, 1.1130464))

fit <- nls(data = df, y ~ (1/(1 + exp(-b*x + c))), start = list(b=1, c=0))
df$stand_alone_fit <- predict(fit, df)

df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  ylim(0,1.2) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = "nls", se = FALSE, 
              method.args = list(formula = y ~ (1/(1 + exp(-b*x + c))), start = list(b= 1, c=0))) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = stand_alone_fit), color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Blue: geom_smooth nls fit\nRed: stand alone nls fit")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here, first the prediction (red line) is only performed at for the x points cause the curve to look boxy and not smooth.

Second and the reason for the question.  The two fitted curves are not equal is because there is transformation on the x axis due to this line `scale_x_log10()` so the nls function inside the geom_smooth is performing a different fit than the standalone fit.

See what happens when the x-axis transformation is removed.  (the green line is a finer prediction from the external fit).

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c(4.63794469, 1.54525711, 0.51508570, 0.17169523, 0.05737664, 5.11623138, 1.70461130, 0.56820377, 0.18940126, 0.06329358, 0.02109786), 
                 "y" = c(0.1460101, 0.7081954, 0.9619413, 1.0192286, 1.0188301, 0.3114495, 0.7602488, 0.8205661, 0.9741323, 1.0922553, 1.1130464))


fit <- nls(data = df, y ~ (1/(1 + exp(-b*x + c))), start = list(b=0, c=0))
df$stand_alone_fit <- predict(fit, df)

#finer resolution (green line)
new <- data.frame(x=seq(0.02, 5.1, 0.1))
new$y <-predict(fit, new)

df %>% ggplot() +
   geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
#   scale_x_log10() +
   ylim(0,1.2) +
   geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = "nls", se = FALSE, 
               method.args = list(formula = y ~  (1/(1 + exp(-b*x + c))), start = list(b=0, c=0))) +
   geom_line(aes(x = x, y = stand_alone_fit), color = "red") +
   geom_line(data=new, aes(x, y), color="green") +
   labs(title = "Blue: geom_smooth nls fit\nRed: stand alone nls fit")
```

[image]

Or use this in your original ggplot definition: `method.args = list(formula = y ~  (1/(1 + exp(-b*10^(x) + 2*c))), start = list(b=-1, c=-3)))`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Log-transforming the data before fitting made me get the same fit with geom_smooth even after scale_x_log10() (I want to plot with log scale).